# Folders have become read only and files write protected when moving data from one PC to another

Tags: usb, read-only, write-protect

I moved some images and videos from laptop A(windows 7) to laptop B(windows 10) via a 16GB USB. But when I tried to copy the files from A to USB, it said the remaining files were 'Write protected' after some files got successfully transferred. I tried to move the data to B but there too I encountered the same problem and ended up successfully transferring only half of the few data that I could get in the USB.

Now I scanned the USB with the antivirus but everything was okay. I tried to get the remaining data from A but this time I couldn't get even one file (including the ones I had previously successfully transferred)transferred. Can't even delete anything from the USB either. All the folders of both of my laptops have now become read-only and I cannot change them at all.

I ran full system scan, boot scan, SFC, chkdsk but everything is fine. Laptop A is very old and there chkdsk cmd did show some errors but it wasn't able to fix those. For B however, everything was fine. B also has been factory reset and got a new SSD placed 2 weeks ago.

I'm quite struck with what to do now to solve this problem so please suggest ways for it.

Edit1: I don't know if this is useful but I deleted some temp files rn. But I cannot delete some 10 odd files permanently form the recycle bin.

Comment: Try a different USB flash drive, a new one. It might simply be failing.

Comment: @JoepvanSteens same problem with a new one too. btw I was able to delete files on the USB mentioned in the post just now.

Comment: Before you change anything (i.e. delete files on Laptop A), you should solve the problem with the disk of Laptop A. Sudden read-only locking hints to severe problems with the integrity of the filesystem. Have a look in the Windows System Log for errors with "disk". If you find lots of I/O-Errors for the "disk", you should think about the personal worth of your data an make a copy. My preferred tools are [ddrescue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ddrescue) (always use with mapfile option) on hardware errors and [testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) using a Linux Live USB stick.

Comment: Folders on Windows have always been marked read-only. You just haven't noticed before. https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/you-cannot-view-or-change-the-read-only-or-the-system-attributes-of-folders-in-windows-server-2003-in-windows-xp-in-windows-vista-or-in-windows-7-55bd5ec5-d19e-6173-0df1-8f5b49247165

Comment: You could try another USB.

Comment: @DavidMarshall in windows 10 and above too?